# rewrite a url to a soap method in iis

Tags: web, redirect, iis, soap, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a URL to a soap method but I seem no to able to figure out what's wrong. I have defined a pattern like  this --> .*/tree/tree/(.*)  with no conditions and no server variables  in the action section I have both used redirect and rewrite to : localhost:2136/sharvand.asmx?op=GetTree but it hasn't worked out. any help will be appreciated
[image]
by the way how can I pass query string as a parameter to the web service

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. which url do you want to redirect to which url? please post more details information about your requirement, i can make demo for you.

Comment: I want to map https://gis.shiraz.ir/tree/tree/ID (This is a parameter )  to a soap Web service sth like this https://gis.shiraz.ir:80/service.asmx/op/gettreeinfo(int Id )

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^tree/tree/(.*)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="gis.shiraz.ir:80/service.asmx/op/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```